# Can I remove WooCommerce main content hook?

Tags: hooks, woocommerce-offtopic

```
<?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_before_main_content hook
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper - 10 (outputs opening divs for the content)
     * @hooked woocommerce_breadcrumb - 20
     */
    //do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' );
?>
```

For now, I'm just commenting it out to disable *before main content* and *after main content*.
Is it possible to do it without modifying the plugin files?

```
<?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_after_main_content hook
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end - 10 (outputs closing divs for the content)
     */
    //do_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content' );
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
remove_action('woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper', 10,0);

remove_action('woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_breadcrumb', 20,0);

remove_action('woocommerce_after_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end', 10,0);
```

I hope it works for you =)